# File Upload Laravel 4

Tags: php, file, laravel, upload

In my opinion all its okej. Please Check:

```
{{ form_open({'url': 'video/subtitle'}, {'files': 'true'}, {'method': 'post'}) }}
                    {{ form_hidden('id') }}
                    {{ form_file('file') }}
                   {{ form_submit('upload', {class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'}) }}
                    {{form_close()}}
```

Controller return 2, I don't know why.:

```
if(Input::hasFile('file'))
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else echo 2;
```

Comment: form_open() is not available in L4, it is in CI, try Form::open(), same for form_close() & you are supposted to send array as pamas. you have syntex error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {{ Form::open(['url' => 'video/subtitle', 'files' => 'true', 'method' => 'post']) }}     
        {{ Form::hidden('name', 'value') }}
        {{ Form::file('file') }}
        {{ Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block']) }}
 {{Form::close()}}
```

Please read the Laravel Documentation.